# Preview Android parou de funcionar após atualização

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, gradle

Trabalho em um projeto android e, após a atualização para o Android Studio 3.0, meu projeto começou a dar problema.

O Preview das minhas activities parou de funcionar, embora o app seja buildado e eu consiga instalar ele no celular/emulador, não consigo ir vendo em tempo real as alterações do layout XML, segue mensagem de erro:

```
Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error.
```

também apecem esses erros:

```
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContextView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
```

Pelo que eu li a respeito neste link: [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44223687/render-error-in-android-studio-3-0-layout-editor) parece ser um problema no Gradle, eu tentei restaurar de uma versão anterior do meu versionamento, mas não obtive alteração nenhuma, segue o gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.golfetto.golfettomobile"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "2017.11.07"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions { javaMaxHeapSize "4g" }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(path: ':componentsutils')
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: 'r05'
    compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.5.1'
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.4'
    compile 'com.sackcentury:shinebutton:0.1.4'
    compile 'net.colindodd:toggleimagebutton:1.2'
    compile 'com.sackcentury:shinebutton:0.1.4'
    compile 'net.colindodd:toggleimagebutton:1.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'br.com.livroandroid:android-utils:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.0.9'
    compile 'se.emilsjolander:sprinkles:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
    compile 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.4@aar'
    compile 'com.antonionicolaspina:revealtextview:2.0'
    compile 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.0.9'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.bcgdv.asia.lib:fanmenu:1.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.2.6'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

EDIT:
ja tentei alterar o tema do projeto, aqui está meu Tema no XML

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

quem puder ajudar, agradeço.

Comment: Estou com o mesmo problema, vou acompanhar essa pergunta, valeu.

Comment: Tive um erro parecido e resolvi mudando de `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
</style>` para `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
</style>` em seu arquivo styles.xml

Comment: @Zulian já tentei fazer isso, também não funcionou :(

Comment: E mudar sua `buildToolsVersion `? Talvez para 25

Comment: @Zulian então, estou usando o Android Studio 3.0.0 e a minima suportada é a versão 26.0.2 (segundo a mensagem de erro que deu quando eu tentei fazer o que você falou)

Comment: Tente actualizando as `com.android.support:xxxxx` para a versão 27.0.0

Comment: Esse vídeo mostra de forma excelente como resolver esse problema em 2 minutos: ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnZaSL_QMPs&feature=youtu.be
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em detrimento a pouco conteúdo em português deste assunto e seguindo a resposta do **ramaral** vou postar aqui a solução do problema.

Ele sugeriu atualizar as bibliotecas para a versão 27, mas usei como base a versão 26, e coloquei tanto o **compileSdkVersion** quanto o **buildToolsVersion** na mesma versão, segue código:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.golfetto.golfettomobile"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "2017.11.07"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions { javaMaxHeapSize "4g" }
}
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

O sistema de actualização faz muito bem o seu trabalho. Siga as instruções por ele indicadas e normalmente tudo correrá bem(no meu caso sempre correu).

O Android Studio depende de outras "ferramentas" para funcionar, nomeadamente do *Build Tools* e do *Gradle plugin*.

Versões diferentes do Android Studio poderão necessitar de diferentes versões dessas "ferramentas".

Como disse atrás, o sistema de actualização garante que elas seja devidamente actualizadas quando necessário, é só seguir as instruções.

No entanto, há ocasiões em que, no que diz respeito ao editor de Layouts, é necessário actualizar as bibliotecas de suporte. Nesta situação, não lhe é dada essa informação durante a actualização.

Abra o builde.gradle do modulo e altere todas as linhas `compile 'com.android.support:xxx:24.2.0` para a versão mais recente, que nesta data é a 27.0.0.

Como "regra de ouro" tenha, sempre que possível, as bibliotecas de suporte, o *Build Tools* o *Gradle plugin* actualizados para a última versão.

**Notas para a versão 3.1.**

- Qualquer ocorrência de `compile`, `testCompile`, `debugCompile` ou `realeseComplile` gerarão *warnings* e no futuro(final de 2018) não poderão ser usadas. Deverá substituí-los por `implementation`, `testImplementation`, `debugImplementation` e `realeseImplementation`, respectivamente.
- Não é mais necessário indicar a `buildToolsVersion`, ela é inferida automaticamente. Deverá por isso eliminá-la.

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado!

Solução para problema de sicroniação gradle versão 28!
Olá funcionou a mesma estrategia para versão 28, passando para versão 27!
Obrigado!

Nome do arquivo xml é "build gradle(Module:app)

- apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  android {
     compileSdkVersion 27

  defaultConfig {

  ```
     applicationId "br.com.giovani.detectarv1"

     minSdkVersion 15

     targetSdkVersion 27

     versionCode 1

     versionName "1.0"

     testInstrumentationRunner
  ```

"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

```
   }

   buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
   } }
```

dependencies {

```
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

   implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'

   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2' }
```