# Como resolver problemas da atualizacao do Android Studio 3.1

Tags: android, android-studio

Olá, eu atualizei o Android Studio semana passada e depois disso ficou complicado de trabalhar.
Ele não identifica mais os imports, não autocompleta mais o código, o Glade tinha parado de compilar mas eu consegui voltar para a versão 3.0.1 e agora consigo compilar. Mas mesmo apresentando esses "erros" ele consegue compilar os projetos.

Alguém pode me ajudar a resolver?

A versão do Android Studio é essa:

```
Android Studio 3.1
Build #AI-173.4670197, built on March 21, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

Erros:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Relacionado https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/253522/2541

Comment: no case dele é o preview dos xml que deu problema, mas no meu não, foi o java mesmo.

Comment: Por isso tive dúvidas em considerar como duplicata. No entanto, o que é dito na resposta a ela, no que se refere a seguir as indicações, é válido para este caso. Sempre que o *build* falha, por causa da actualização, além da descrição do problema, é-lhe apresentado a forma de resolver(na forma de link), basta clicar nele.

Comment: aham, como eu disse consigo fazer o build e instalar meus projetos, só me atrapalha no Editor de código.

Comment: Peço desculpa, não li bem a pergunta. Sugiro que actualize o Android Studio para o 3.1 e siga as instruções para actualizar o projecto.

Comment: é justamente a versao 3.1 que tenho

Comment: Agora fiquei confuso pois você diz: *"o Glade tinha parado de compilar mas eu consegui voltar para a versão 3.0.1 e agora consigo compilar."*

Comment: Você já tentou `Tools -> Android -> Sync Project With Gradle Files`?

Comment: Se criar um projeto do ZERO, o editor funciona?

Comment: meu problema @ramaral seria só dele nao encontra os imports e não autocompletar mais o código, mas ele faz build sim, somente na edição do código, na programação que nao funciona.